# Does interference pattern depends upon the material used to make slits?

Tags: photons, double-slit-experiment, interference

Is the interference pattern independent of the material from which the slits are made or is it dependent upon the type of material in some way?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not depend on the material used to make the slits. It depends on the wavelength and the slit width.

Comment: of course it does matter, imagine what would happen if the screen is made of a dielectric whose susceptibility is only 0.01, ie., $\epsilon \approx 1.01$, the diffraction pattern would obviously look very different than if it were made of metal.